# Azure Error: Client side authentication flow with Google is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I suddenly started to receive the following error in my app. I'm sure it has been running fine before - atleast on my machine :-)

```
Error: Client side authentication flow with Google is not supported.
```

I get this error when I try to login using a accesstoken I've received from a gapi authorize call:

```
// login with google using gapi    
gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: noPopup }, 
     function (authResult) {
         // Pass the accesstoken into azure
         client.login("google",  {"access_token": authResult.access_token}).then(
              function(user) {
                   // logged into azure...
```

Then I receive the error about not supported flow.

(if I change from "google" to "facebook", the error is: Error: The Facebook Graph API access token authorization request failed with HTTP status code 400 - which makes sence since it's a google accesstoken I'm passing in)

If I paste in the url directly in a browser https://kjokken.azure-mobile.net/login/google, then everything seems to be ok.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using Mobile Services and taking the time to report this. We actively working on adding support for this particular scenario over the next couple of weeks, which explains what you are seeing. I will update this post when we have more information.

In the interim, did you consider using `MobileServiceClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider, UserAuthenticationCallback callback)`?

Thanks,
-Yavor

Comment: ok, thanks for answering. I'll mark the answer as accepted when you update it. I did not understand you're suggestion using the callback. I did not see it documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554236.aspx

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were using JavaScript. The "token" parameter is optional, which will cause the login method to do a OAuth-based flow. [Check this out.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-html/)

Comment: Hy... I am trying to login the user "sillently" the second time he enters the app...when I try to login with google with the jToken method I get this: ":  The POST Google login request must contain both code and id_token in the body of the request". Any suggestions Yavor?

Comment: The flow that takes `JToken` continues to be unsupported, see [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/issues/185). To enable "silent" authentication, you can still use the other flow (use the method in my answer). After the first successful login, call [`getCurrentUser()`](http://dl.windowsazure.com/androiddocs/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.html#getCurrentUser()) and store that value securely. On the next app launch use `setCurrentUser()` and don't call `login`... that should work.